# TwitterKit filter timeline but inversely?

Tags: twitter, twitter-fabric

I'm displaying a twitter timeline in my app via `Fabric` `TwitterKit`.

I want to filter the timeline by showing only tweets @ a specific user. I've read the documentation from [here](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/twitter/show-timelines.html#filter-timeline) on how to filter tweets in the timeline. Unfortunately for me, the function they provide will exclude any tweet that contains the specified keyword/s in the timeline.

The behavior I'm looking for is one that will include only the tweets that contain the specified keyword/s in the timeline.

Is this possible to do with TwitterKit? I've been searching for an inverse filter for this but there seems to be none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it is not clear what is your source timeline. Have you considered using [TWTRSearchTimelineDataSource](https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/ios/show-timelines#search-timeline) and configuring [Search API query](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search#query-operators)? The Search API supports compound queries with some logical functions, so you might be able to create a query that will cover all your needs.

**Note**: given the link you provided in your question I assume your target platform is iOS. You can apply similar solution for Android.

If the Search API is not powerful enough for you, your other choice is to do some client-side filtering.  I was not able to find iOS source code but some version of [Twitter Kit for Android](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-android/) is available at GitHub. If you look at [BasicTimelineFilter](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-android/blob/master/tweet-ui/src/main/java/com/twitter/sdk/android/tweetui/BasicTimelineFilter.java) and 
[FilterTimelineDelegate](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-android/blob/master/tweet-ui/src/main/java/com/twitter/sdk/android/tweetui/FilterTimelineDelegate.java), you can see that in Android filtering is actually performed on the client side. So you can do the same with any custom filtering in your iOS application. All you need is create a wrapper class that will implement [TWTRTimelineDataSource](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/TwitterKit/2.7.0/Protocols/TWTRTimelineDataSource.html) protocol and do your custom filtering. Here is some sketch of how the code might look like in Objective-C (you can do the same in Swift of course):

***Note:*** beware of bugs, I haven't even compiled this code

.h file

```
typedef BOOL (^SOTweetFilter)(TWTRTweet * tweet);

@interface SOFilteredTimelineDataSourceWrapper : NSObject<TWTRTimelineDataSource>

- (instancetype)initWithDataSource:(id<TWTRTimelineDataSource>)dataSource filter:(SOTweetFilter)filter;

@end
```

.m file

```
@implementation SOFilteredTimelineDataSourceWrapper
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) id<TWTRTimelineDataSource> wrapped;
@property (nonatomic, copy) SOTweetFilter filter;

- (instancetype)initWithDataSource:(id<TWTRTimelineDataSource>)dataSource filter:(SOTweetFilter)filter {
    if(!(self = [super init])) return self;

    self.wrapped = dataSource;
    self.filter = filter;

    return self;
}

- (void)loadPreviousTweetsBeforePosition:(nullable NSString *)position completion:(TWTRLoadTimelineCompletion)completion {
    // typedef void (^TWTRLoadTimelineCompletion)(NSArray<TWTRTweet *> * _Nullable tweets, TWTRTimelineCursor * _Nullable cursor, NSError * _Nullable error);
    [wrapped loadPreviousTweetsBeforePosition:position completion:^(NSArray<TWTRTweet *> * _Nullable tweets, TWTRTimelineCursor * _Nullable cursor, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if(error) {
                // forward error
                completion(tweets, cursor, error);
            }
            else {
                // filter results
                NSArray* filtered = [tweets filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *bindings) {
                    return self.filter(evaluatedObject);
                }]];
                completion(filtered, cursor, error);
            }
    }];
}


// delegate all properties to the wrapped

- (TWTRTimelineType)timelineType {
    return wrapped.timelineType;
}

-(TWTRTimelineFilter *)timelineFilter {
    return wrapped.timelineFilter;
}

-(void)setTimelineFilter:(TWTRTimelineFilter *)timelineFilter {
    wrapped.timelineFilter = timelineFilter;
}

- (TWTRAPIClient *)APIClient{ 
    return wrapped.APIClient;
}

- (void)setAPIClient:(TWTRAPIClient *)APIClient{ 
    wrapped.APIClient = APIClient;
}

@end
```

The main idea is that you intercept `loadPreviousTweetsBeforePosition:completion:` call and add your additional processing before calling the original `completion` callback. Using such `SOFilteredTimelineDataSourceWrapper` you can wrap any other `TWTRTimelineDataSource` and do any filtering you want analyzing [TWTRTweet.text](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/TwitterKit/2.7.0/Classes/TWTRTweet.html#//api/name/text). For mentions (i.e. handle-based) filtering you might want to take a look at Android implementation of [normalizeHandle](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-android/blob/master/tweet-ui/src/main/java/com/twitter/sdk/android/tweetui/BasicTimelineFilter.java#L204).

Comment: Appreciate the detailed information! Sorry I forgot to mention my source timeline. It would be of a specific user's timeline (`TWTRUserTimelineDataSource`). I would only want to display tweets that contain specific mentions to another user and exclude the rest. Would it be the same approach as the solution you suggested above using the `Search API`?

Comment: @aresz, given such requirements I would try using `TWTRSearchTimelineDataSource` with search query `from:author_user_account @mentioned_user_account`. There is a possible drawback mentioned in the documentation: you might get only relatively short history of about 1 week. If this is the case for this query and it is not acceptable for you, you might have to switch to local filtering as described in the second part of my answer.

Comment: Ah I see. The 1 week short history is not ideal for the app I'm making so I may have to go for the local filtering route you mentioned. I'll go ahead and proceed with that. Thank you.

Comment: @aresz, I suggest you first to try `TWTRSearchTimelineDataSource` anyway. I suspect that history limit might be different for different kinds of queries